# Network Settings for ElasticSearch from Azure

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

I am trying to setup an ElasticSearch cluster on Azure.

I can access it from localhost, but not from any other machine.   What do i have to set my configuration to (in either Azure or ElasticSearch config) to allow another cloud app to connect to my instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Windows Firewall was blocking my port (9200) on the VM.

Going into windows firewall and enabling it fixed the problem.

Comment: You might want to accept your own answer as your fixed your issue yourself ;)

Comment: Have you tried specifying internal endpoint in your ServiceDefinition.csdef? It will solve your problem without manually configuring Windows Firewall?